# JFoenix cannot access cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jfoenix, openfx

I would like to use JFoenix but when I want to use a JFXProgressBar or JFXSpinner I have this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.jfoenix.skins.JFXProgressBarSkin (in unnamed module @0x6aac0b03) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene to unnamed module @0x6aac0b03
```

I tried to change my jdk version (11 to 13) my openFx version (11 to 13). Create the project with and without maven but none of this worked. I have the same error when i tried to use GluonSkin on Spinner.

This is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>RosettaBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfoenix/jfoenix -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.36.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>rosettastone.sample.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This has to do with Modules. One way is to add an export via vm options or to add java fx not on the module path but on the class path. Or go back to jdk 8 since modules did not exist back then. I guess jfx is using internal javafx classes. --add-export=... u need to do maybe read some stuff about java modules and u might understand what is going on.

Comment: i already tried to add all java modules but it didnt work...